# How to tell what part in a Macbook Pro is broken if screen backlight don't work?

Tags: hardware-failure, macbook, backlight

I have an early 2015 Macbook Pro that don't have a backlight in the screen. However I can still use the mac if I plug in to a monitor. I'm wondering if it is a problem with the screen or some other part. The Mac was damaged by rain.

1. What are the possible parts that broke?
2. Is it possible to check with a multi-meter?

Suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Either the backlight itself or the inverter that supplies the power it needs.

Comment: The 2015 early macbook pro do not have an inverter. Does that mean I would have to replace the motherboard?

Comment: Yes if the inverter it is part of the motherboard.

Comment: can you see any image on the display, when the back light goes out you can still see an image in certain lighting and angle.  If you have no image what so ever than the display may also be damaged.

Comment: You can see image if you flash light at it.